How to adjust audio volume with AVFilter API from FFmpeg in Linux?
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), and developing an audio player by using FFmpeg and ALSA libraries.
Now the basic functions are done, and I can play MP3 file by using AVCodec and SWresample interfaces of FFmpeg.
int decode_play(void)
{
    .....
    while (1) {
        if (av_read_frame(pfmtctx, packet) < 0) {
            avcodec_flush_buffers(pcodectx);
            printf("Got end of media, breaking\n");
            break;
        }
        if (packet->stream_index != stream) {
            continue;
        }
        int res = avcodec_send_packet(pcodectx, packet);
        if (res < 0) {
            printf("Error in decoding audio frame.\n");
            break;
        }

        while (res >= 0) {
            res = avcodec_receive_frame(pcodectx, pframe);
            if (res == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                break;
            } else if (res == AVERROR_EOF) {
                break;
            } else if (res >= 0) {
                int outsamples = swr_convert(swrctx, &buf, pcodectx->frame_size, (const uint8_t **)pframe->data, pframe->nb_samples);
                snd_pcm_write(pcm_handle, buf, outsamples);
            }
        }
    }
}

Now, I want to add volume changing to this audio player.
I found that there is AVfilter functions in FFmpeg, which can be used to adjust audio's volume.  How can I use it in current design?
I am not sure what filters should I use, and where should I plugin the filters?
Should I put the filters before swr_convert or after the swr_convert?
With Erdal's help, I changed the player as follows,
int decode_play(void)
{
    /* Init filter graph as filter_audio.c does */
    init_filter_graph(&graph, &src, &sink);

    while (1) {
        if (av_read_frame(pfmtctx, packet) < 0) {
            avcodec_flush_buffers(pcodectx);
            printf("Got end of media, breaking\n");
            break;
        }
        if (packet->stream_index != stream) {
            continue;
        }
        int res = avcodec_send_packet(pcodectx, packet);
        if (res < 0) {
            printf("Error in decoding audio frame.\n");
            break;
        }

        while (res >= 0) {
            res = avcodec_receive_frame(pcodectx, pframe);
            if (res == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                break;
            } else if (res == AVERROR_EOF) {
                break;
            } else if (res >= 0) {
                int ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame(src, pframe);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                while ((ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(sink, filt_frame)) >= 0) {
                    int nb_samples = av_rescale_rnd(filt_frame->nb_samples, RESAMPLE_SAMPLE_RATE, filt_frame->sample_rate, AV_ROUND_UP);
                    printf("nb_samples: %d, f.nb_sample: %d, f.sr: %d\n", nb_samples, filt_frame->nb_samples, filt_frame->sample_rate);

                    int outs = snd_pcm_writei(playback_handle, filt_frame->extended_data[0], nb_samples);
                    if (outs < 0) {
                        snd_pcm_prepare(playback_handle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The original audio in format of 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp. And I chose to use aformat to do resampling instead of swresample as follows.
    snprintf(options_str, sizeof(options_str),
            "sample_fmts=%s:sample_rates=%d:channel_layouts=stereo",
            av_get_sample_fmt_name(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16), 32000);
    if (avfilter_init_str(aformat_ctx, options_str) < 0) {
        printf("error init aformat filter");
        return -1;
    }

I succeeded playing the resampled audio with Avfilter.

libavfilter Reference: libavfilter. Audio filter example: filter_audio.c. FFmpeg Filter Reference: FFmpeg Filters Documentation. The one you're looking for (accepted parameters and their descriptions): 8.120 volume.

In case i misunderstood you. If you're going to build a filtergraph, don't resample yourself, simply add a resample filter: aformat. Check out the linked example in my previous comment, both "volume" and "aformat" filters are used.

Thanks for comment. I got an example of avfilter, which uses 4 filters: abuffer, volume, aformat and abuffersink. I am not sure in my volume changing case, are these 4 filters all needed, or just only aformat and volume are enough? If so, I also need to figure out how to link them into my current player......

You want to feed the graph and want it to output something, right? So abuffer and abuffersink are somewhat required. Again, to make your life easier, study the example, it does exactly what you want to do (resample + volume).

Got you. I am reading the filter_audio.c.....Will update with my comments or questions.

If you look at the main function of the example, for each sample, it reads a frame from the input (ok, the example synthesizes it on the fly, but you would read it from the source file), then passes that frame to the src filter context, afterwards it retrieves in a loop all the filtered output that is available from the sink filter context, which you then could use those frames however you like (most likely write it to the output file). The init_filter_graph function initializes the src and sink filter contexts accordingly.

Got you. From the quick reading of the example, it links the filters as follows: abuffer->volume->aformat->abuffersink. So I need to get the output frames from abuffersink and pass them to swr_convert then play them out. I would follow the example when updating my player.

Why extra conversion, aformat does that already. If you want your own conversion, then leave aformat out, just use the volume filter. But then i also would recommend to avoid the filter mechanism and simply multiply the samples by a volume factor [0..1.0] and clamp it to a min/max value. I would apply the volume to the sound with the highest quality (so either before or after conversion, depends if you scale down or up). Well to be honest, i am no mathematician, so i don't know if that would even matter.

I don't know how to use aformat to do resampling, still studying. You are right, I can change the volume by multiplying samples with volume factor, but it still need to do clamping, so I would try avfilter first.  Another question is, is it possible to change the volume during the media playing with avfilter dynamically???

Yes, either via avfilter_init_str or avfilter_init_dict (which do the same thing but with different calling convention).

BTW, clamp is simple: min(max(x, xmin), xmax) and only necessary if the factor is outside the range [0..1], so if one can guarantee that it will never exceed this range, no clamp required.

OK, let me firstly make avfilter work (changing the volume run-time). @Erdal, you can post something as the answer. Thank you for your assistance.
